# Reading HTML, how to skip HEAD tag info in a webpage using a BufferedReader, reading the HTML line by line?

Tags: java, html, bufferedreader

I have a quick question that I am having a hard time figuring out. I want to read an html file line by line but I want to skip over the HEAD tag. Therefore, I figured that I could start reading the text after skipping past the HEAD tag.

So far I have created:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("<html>")) 
        string.append(line + "\n");
}
```

I want to save the html code in memory without the HEAD information.

Example:

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>

    <TITLE>Your Title Here</TITLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFF">

    <CENTER><IMG SRC="clouds.jpg" ALIGN="BOTTOM"> </CENTER>

    <a href="http://somegreatsite.com">Link Name</a>is a link to another nifty site

    <H1>This is a Header</H1>

    <H2>This is a Medium Header</H2>

    Send me mail at <a href="mailto:support@yourcompany.com">support@yourcompany.com</a>.

</BODY>
```

I want to save everything but the  tag information.

Comment: There is no such thing as HTML headers. There are HTTP headers. Is that what you mean? Why are you using a socket instead of a proper HTTP client to make an HTTP request?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes. Thats what I mean. I apologize. Im currently calling a method creates an HTTP request. I was going to post the entire code.

Comment: While searching for the html tag may work in your situation, remember that in general, the HTML start tag is optional, so may not appear at all in an arbitrary HTML file. On the other hand, the HTTP headers are really easy to skip. Just read the lines from the start until you hit a empty line. The HTML will start immediately following that.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem: OP should be using an HTTP client, and perhaps also an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this -

```
boolean htmlFound = false;                        // Have we found an open html tag?
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();       // Back to your code...
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  if (!htmlFound) {                               // Have we found it yet?
    if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("<html")) { // Check if this line opens a html tag...
      htmlFound = true;                           // yes? Excellent!
    } else {
      continue;                                   // Skip over this line...
    }
  }
  System.out.println("This is each line: " + line);
  string.append(line + "\n");
}
```